# Getting 400 for Spring RestTemplate POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am getting a 400 error while using resttempalate for a POST call in spring boot app.

Here is my code :

```
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
     headers.add("Accept", "application/json");
     request = "{ json : string }";
     url = "http://localhost:9082/restws";
     HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request , headers);
     return restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
```

Stack Trace:

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:380)
    at com.envision.application.web.rest.EngineResource.getModelParams(EngineResource.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)

2018-06-05 14:26:58.064 ERROR 42744 --- [XNIO-13 task-38] c.e.a.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator  : An unexpected error occurred: 400 
2018-06-05 14:26:58.069  WARN 42744 --- [XNIO-13 task-38] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400

Comment: can you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

it is not a valid json. enclose key and value in double quotes.

Comment: I did post the actual json. I did tried with a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

You are forming a bad request, try to change the request body.

```
String request = " {  \"json\" : \"string\" }" ;
```

Comment: I did post the actual json. I did tried with a valid json.

Comment: Can you share the specification of the service you try to consume

Answer (score 0):

It works now. JSON parser at rest endpoint  needed double quotes around field names. Thanks everyone one for helping.